# swap memory in C++

Tags: c++, memcpy

I am trying to swap some register values on the Stack. e.g. L0,L1...L10 should become L10,L9,..L0. These register values are stored in the buffer "target_types::buf".

```
void reverse_local_regs(int size, int offset)
{
  const int BYTES_PER_REGISTER = 4;
  uint8_t temp_reg[BYTES_PER_REGISTER];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i += BYTES_PER_REGISTER)
  {
    memcpy(temp_reg, &target_types::buf[offset + i], BYTES_PER_REGISTER);
    memcpy(&target_types::buf[offset + i], &target_types::buf[offset + size - i - 4], BYTES_PER_REGISTER);
    memcpy(&target_types::buf[offset + size - i - 4], temp_reg, BYTES_PER_REGISTER);
  }
}
```

I wrote this function but it does not change the memory at all. To verify that the memory stays the same I wrote the following code which prints "Same mem".

```
  uint8_t test[2048];
  memcpy(test, target_types::buf, 2048);
  reverse_local_regs(BYTES_PER_REGISTER * FL, FP_SR_PC_offset);
  if (memcmp(test, target_types::buf, 2048) == 0)
    std::cout << "Same mem" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "different mem" << std::endl;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to debug the program and observe the effects of memory reads, writes?

Comment: Maybe go from `0` to `size/2`.  I think you may be swapping everything and then swapping it back.

Comment: thank you very much @SteveSummit i'm stupid that was the problem.

Comment: @SimonRechermann Don't feel "stupid": mistakes like this are easy to make, but are how we learn! The other thing to do is to convince yourself that `size/2` is correct, that there's no off-by-one error, that it works correctly regardless of whether `size` is even or odd.  (Hint: `size/2` *is* correct, but it's a good exercise to convince yourself.)

Comment: `std::reverse(target_types::buf + offset, target_types::buf + offset + size)` will presumably do the job in a single line of code but difficult to tell without a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it needs parentheses
also iterator `i` should stop at half `size`
otherwise it will swap back in the second half

```
void reverse_local_regs(int size, int offset)
{
  const int BYTES_PER_REGISTER = 4;
  uint8_t temp_reg[BYTES_PER_REGISTER];
  for (int i = 0; i < size/2; i += BYTES_PER_REGISTER)
  {
    memcpy(temp_reg, &target_types::buf[offset + i], BYTES_PER_REGISTER);
    memcpy(&target_types::buf[offset + i], &target_types::buf[offset + (size - (i + 4))], BYTES_PER_REGISTER);
    memcpy(&target_types::buf[offset + (size - (i + 4))], temp_reg, BYTES_PER_REGISTER);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. Like Steve commented I had to use `size/2`. The parentheses are not necessary.